# Nodejs / Expressjs Cannot link to css file

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying out node / express js and created a little web project.

I have the views in root /views  directory

so:

```
root
  /views
  /css
```

I've added this to /views/index.html file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
```

And this is my server.js file code:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var path = __dirname + '/views/';
var path = __dirname + '/css/'; //Not working

router.use(function (req,res,next) {
  console.log("/" + req.method);
  next();
});

router.get("/",function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path + "index.html");
});

router.get("/about",function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path + "about.html");
});

router.get("/contact",function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path + "contact.html");
});

app.use("/",router);

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use("*",function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path + "404.html");
});

app.listen(3000,function(){
  console.log("Live at Port 3000 - http://localhost:3000");
});
```

How can I get it to read my css files?

Comment: See http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: I'm getting this error now after adding that code: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/var/www/html/css/index.html'
   at Error (native)

Comment: Try this: `app.use('/css', express.static('css'));`. I see that you just copy-pasted key line from the docs page I linked to - you have to make sure it's pointing at the right path specific to your project.

Comment: You want to create an answer ? It was you who solved the issue so I think it's fair that you get the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To serve static files using Express.JS, use its built-in [`express.static` middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

Assuming following directory structure:

```
root/
  server.js
  css/
    styles.css
```

All you need is the following code in your `server.js` file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// key line! - serve all static files from "css" directory under "/css" path
app.use('/css', express.static('css'));

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Live at Port 3000 - http://localhost:3000');
});
```

To make `styles.css` available under `localhost:3000/css/styles.css` address (and analogically for all other files kept in `css` directory).